# Applying a two-parameter function to a matrix, being the indexes of the matrix the arguments

Tags: matrix

I want to multiply every element of a 782x782 matrix with a function that depends on the two indexes of that element, I tried `MapIndexed`, but I don't seem to fully understand how it works.

The function is :

```
f[x_, y_] := Exp[I*(2 Pi/\[Lambda]g)*zi*Sqrt[1 - (\[Lambda]g*x/(2*a*dx))^2 + (\[Lambda]g*y/(2*b*dx))^2]]
```

where `x` and `y`, are the indexes of the elements, and everything else already defined constants.

That function is independent of the actual value of the matrix, I just care about how to transmit the index information.

I thought about using MapIndexed to give it the index information, but I don't seem to fully grasp how to do that. Is there another easier way, or just a correct way of doing this that you can think of?

Thanks in advance.

Edit : Sorry, 782x782, but I'm guessing your answers can be used just changing the 2x2.

Comment: Letting `mat` be the original matrix, try `mat Array[f, {2, 2}]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
A  = Array[a, {2, 3}]
matf = Table[f[x, y], {x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, 3}]
matf A  (* elementwise multiplication *)
```

Answer (score 0):

> ***I tried MapIndexed, but ...***

Using @Ulrich's example `A  = Array[a, {2, 3}]`

```
MapIndexed[# f @@ #2 &, A, {2}]
```

> {{a[1, 1] f[1, 1], a[1, 2] f[1, 2],  a[1, 3] f[1, 3]},
>     {a[2, 1] f[2, 1], a[2, 2] f[2, 2],  a[2, 3] f[2, 3]}}